# Docker volume stops getting in sync

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-volume

I'm using docker on windows with wsl.

I think i set it up correctly because i was working on it successfully for almost 3 months without problems, but yesterday i updated docker to the last version (19.03.5) and now my volumes are not synchronizing the files correctly. I have to do a `docker-compose restart` for being able to see the files correctly.

On wsl i mounted `C:` under `/c/`:

here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    build: ./php
    container_name: php
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ../../WWW:/code
      - /code/treddy/api/vendor
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ../../WWW:/code
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - php

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

Sometimes when i restart docker, it seems that all works correctly but after some edits to files the volume stops to sync files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade to 2.1.0.5 or try this solution https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5530#issuecomment-578228528

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you give some more details on why downgrading is a good solution, and how the content of the linked page supports that suggestion? It's best when answers are self-supporting without relying on external links.

Comment: There is a bug with filesystem caching in Docker for Windows 2.2.0.0. This bug don't relies on wsl. In my case solution mensioned in link below solves problem but adds some new. After downgrading all works perfectly, but it requires full rebuild.